# Anyone for cake?

Tags: discussion

The Great Geobakeoff has produced some wonderful results : https://www.flickr.com/photos/99330142@N05/sets/72157644551255832/

Comment: What's the license for the images? Some of them could be used as promotional material for the ES site.

Comment: @DeerHunter well, Flickr has them registered as "All rights reserved". But, I suspect that that account collects them from elsewhere, so I really have no idea who one would need to ask for permission.